# Couchbase Server - Cannot do a Get or Set if One Node Stopped

Tags: memcached, couchbase

I set up Couchbase 1.8 cluster on two nodes (Windows 2008 R2).

1) Opened up all the necessary ports on the two servers as outlined here:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-network-ports.html

2) I did a simple setup, initially creating Node A (172.30.75.53) on a new Cluster.
Changed the IPAddress to the Static IPAddress of the server as outlined here:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html
Created using the default Couchbase bucket.

3) Then installed Couchbase on Node B  (172.30.75.55).
Changed the IPAddress to the Static IPAddress of the server.

4) Back on Node A, I added Node B to the cluster.

5) Did the initial re-balance in the Couchbase web console.

6) In the Couchbase console, I could then see the two nodes up and running.

I created a simple app C# sample app to test as below:

In the config file pointed to Node A

```
var client = new CouchbaseClient();
var setResult = client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "someKey", "someData", new    TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)); 
var resultGet = client.ExecuteGet<string>("someKey");
```

Could then do a Get and Set with no issues (as expected).

Then in my config file, changed to point to Node B.

Could then do a Get as below (as expected):
    var resultGet = client.ExecuteGet("someKey");

On Node A, shut down the CouchBase service by running:
service_stop.bat

With my test app still pointing to Node B, could still get and set (as expected).

On Node A, started the Couchbase Service by running:
service_start.bat
On Node B, shut down the CouchBase service by running:
service_stop.bat

Then in my config file, changed to point to Node A.

Now when trying to do a Get and Set as below while connected to Node A:
    var setResult = client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "someKey", "someData", new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)); 
    var resultGet = client.ExecuteGet("someKey");

Getting errors as below:

-Store operation failed, see InnerResult or StatusCode for details"
-Failed to Execute Operation
-StatusCode : 0

Get failed. See InnerException or StatusCode for details"
StatusCode : Null

Therefore to conclude:

a) Can do a Get and Set with Node A and Node B are running. (with client connected to Node A or Node B)

b) Can do a Get and Set With Node A stopped and Node B running. (with client connected to Node B)

c) CANNOT do a Get and Set With Node A running and Node B stopped. (with client connected to Node A)

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are doing a single get/set on a single key for your test. If this is the case then what is happening is that that key is on Node B so when you stop Node B the key cannot be found. With Couchbase when a node is down the data to it will be inaccessible until you fail that node over. If you were running in production what you would do if Node B  was malfunctioning is fail that node over and then once you fixed whatever problem the node was having you would add it back and rebalance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it is possible for Couchbase to do this automatically. i.e. Fail the node over with no intervention?

Comment: I had Enable Auto Failover set on my Cluster, but I only have two nodes. Looks like you have to have > 2 nodes for Auto Failover to work.

Comment: I believe that you have to have at least 3 nodes in order to use the auto failover feature.

Comment: Yes, for two nodes, auto failover is disabled. Or is according to: http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Autofailover+behavior